# How to change the value that a template string extrapolates

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, template-strings

I'm trying to write a simple Id monad to play around with and learn.

Here is what I've written:

```
const util = require('util');

const Id = x => ({
  [util.inspect.custom]: () => `Id(${x})`,
  map: f => Id.of(f(x)),
  flatMap: f => f(x),
  valueOf: () => `Id(${x})`,
});

Id.of = Id;

const foo = Id.of('foo');
const toUpper = str => Id.of(str.toUpperCase());

const fooBoxed = foo.map(toUpper); // Oh oh, should be Id(Id('FOO'));
const FOO = foo.flatMap(toUpper); // Yay, Id('FOO');

console.log(fooBoxed);
console.log(FOO);
```

`fooBoxed` should log out `Id(Id(Foo))`, but it logs out `Id([object object])`.
I tried modifying `valueOf` and `inspect` but both doesn't work. I suspect that `${x}` calls a different method and I couldn't find on the internet which that is. What do I have to modify so that `${x}` returns the correct string for my nested `Id` monad?

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve here?

Comment: Shouldn't `valueOf()` return `x`? Otherwise there seems to be no way to unbox the value.

Comment: related but doesn't solve your problem: [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to overwrite `toString`, not `valueOf`. Concatenating with a string (or interpolating a template string) will coerce the value to a string, and your objects inherit `Object.prototype.toString` which returns `[object …]`.

```js
const Id = x => ({
  toString: () => `Id(${x})`,
  map: f => Id.of(f(x)),
  flatMap: f => f(x),
});

Id.of = Id;

const foo = Id.of('foo');
const toUpper = str => Id.of(str.toUpperCase());

const fooBoxed = foo.map(toUpper);
const FOO = foo.flatMap(toUpper);

console.log(fooBoxed.toString()); // Yay, Id(Id('FOO'));
console.log(FOO.toString()); // Yay, Id('FOO');
```

However, since you seem to intend to use this for debugging, you should actually use the debugging representation of your `x` value. To do that, call [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) yourself:

```
const util = require('util');

const Id = x => ({
  [util.inspect.custom]: () => `Id(${util.inspect(x)})`,
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  map: f => Id.of(f(x)),
  flatMap: f => f(x),
  valueOf: () => x,
});
Id.of = Id;
```